# Can multiple threads able to use the same client.id in apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to create an application that consume from apache-kafka using several threads.

Should I configure each thread with different client.id? or is it possible that all of them will have the same one?

I am using kafka-client 0.9

Comment: Do you want the different threads to repetitively process the same event, or will each event be processed by a single thread? Look up [Kafka consumer groups](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example)

Comment: same event, I want all threads to consume messages.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no.

Tested with kafka-clients 0.11.0.0, but the code related to this hasn't changed for two years.

You would get a `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.consumer:type=app-info,id=<client.id>` if you tried to re-use the same client.id inside the same JVM instance.

Further reading on this topic: [KAFKA-3992](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3992?focusedCommentId=15823394&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15823394)

Answer (score 0):

Every thread in your case is a logical 'application', so you should define different ids. In this case every event will be consumed by every single thread.

But if you want your consumer to work as a group - you have to define the same 'group.id' by every consumer (in this case all events will be evenly distributed between all threads).

Comment: they are all using the same group.id, my question is if using the same client.id for all of them will work

Comment: @guy in this case all your consumers will look the same for your broker. I don't know any issues with that. In all my consumers I have something like UUID in consumer name, so every consumer instance automatically has a unique id.